# drupal 8 Functions to support theming preprocess node get paragraph item

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

I'm usign the module Paragraphs for Drupal 8. I need to print the raw value of a paragraph field in the twig template ? 
preprocess my preprocess is like this : mythemename.theme

Answer (score 0):

What you probably should do is create a special twig template for your paragraph type for example if you have a paragraph type "text-paragraph" on the content type article. It would be something like this

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
  ]
%}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  {{ content|raw }}
</div>
```

Ofcourse you can change the div/classes to your liking or remove them altogether.

The file youw ill need ti place it in then would be

> paragraph--paragraph-text--article.html.twig

If you turn on twig debugging in

> sites/default/services.yml

you should be able to see what the suggested template names are for your paragraph if you look at the html source.

Comment: {% for item in content.field_instruction_suitable %}
                  {% if item['#title'] %}
                      <img class="item fl" src="{{ file_url(item['#options'].entity.field_instruction_suitable_image.0.entity.uri.value) }}" alt="{{ item['#title'] }}" class="mgr5">
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}